# Difference between Batch Status and Exit Status in Spring Batch

Tags: spring, spring-batch

Difference between **Batch Status** and **Exit Status** in Spring Batch

Answer (score 24, accepted):

From the Spring Batch [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/htmlsingle):

*A BatchStatus object that indicates the status of the execution. While running, it's BatchStatus.STARTED, if it fails, it's BatchStatus.FAILED, and if it finishes successfully, it's BatchStatus.COMPLETED*

*The ExitStatus indicating the result of the run. It is most important because it contains an exit code that will be returned to the caller.*

For more on the difference, see the section [5.3.2.1. Batch Status vs. Exit Status](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/htmlsingle/#batchStatusVsExitStatus). You will find the explanation is quite good.

Comment: But I have some Steps that have a status of "STARTING" but they got messed up or something and have a exit_code of "EXECUTING" - what exactly causes this and I'm assuming its safe to say this is basically a failure?

Comment: Updated Link to the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/5.1/step/controlling-flow.html#batchStatusVsExitStatus)