# Restart Job option is not enabled in SPring XD Admin Console

Tags: spring-xd

I have deployed a restartable job in Spring XD, and it is FAILED due to some errors. But I am not able to restart the job from the admin console. Did I miss any configurations?

My job configuration looks as below.

```
    <batch:job id="testjob" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch" restartable = "true">
    <batch:step id="taskOne" next="taskTwo">
        <batch:tasklet ref="task1" />
    </batch:step>
    <batch:step id="taskTwo" next="taskThree">
        <batch:tasklet ref="task2" />
    </batch:step>
    <batch:step id="taskThree">
        <batch:tasklet ref="task3" />
    </batch:step>
</batch:job>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your job's Batch Status makes it not restartable even though it's ExitStatus is failed. Do you see this on your log:

> "Encountered fatal error executing job"

I have just tried to restart a `restartable` job whose ExitStatus was `failed` and I could re-start the failed job.

Please see the differences between BatchStatus and ExitStatus:
[Difference between Batch Status and Exit Status in Spring Batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20463904/difference-between-batch-status-and-exit-status-in-spring-batch)

Comment: The log shows "Encountered an error executing step abc in job xyz". I can see the Job Status and Exit Code as FAILED in the admin console. But still the Restart Button is not enabled.